# jsp useBean spring instance null

Tags: spring, jsp, javabeans

Why the different results?

1. is controller code
2. is jsp:useBean code ( .tag file )

I know that an instance generated by the spring is available throughresource.

Thank you for your help.

1) controller

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/healthqna")
    public class CounselController {

         @Resource(name="counselDAO")
         private CounselDAO counselDAO;

         @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
         public string list() {
             counselService.getList(); // **Working !!**

         }
     }
```

2. Bean

   ```
   public class HealthQnATodayTAG {

       @Resource(name="counselDAO")
       private CounselDAO counselDAO;

       public HealthQnATodayTAG() {

            counselService.getList(); // **Did Not Working !!**

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: resources gets injected after construction of object.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom Tag is not a Spring managed bean and so resources will never be injected. You need to load the Model attribute in your controller, set it as a model attribute with required scope and then:

[1] pass it as a parameter to your Tag.

```
<x:myTag list="${list}"/>
```

or

[2] Have your custom Tag extend javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport which will give you a reference to the PageContext and from which you can then get a handle on the Model attribute.

```
pageContext.getAttribute("list");
```